# Duda sobre como mostrar una lista de datos en forma de <li> <li/> o "Punteo de datos" en la capa de HTML?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, .net

Muy buenas tardes a todos

Estoy intentando mostrar una lista de datos la cual es llenada antes en el Backend y mostrarla
en el HTML pero que cada elemento de la lista se muestre como un "Punteo" como por ejemplo asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el formato debe mostrarse asi tal cual ya que es llegar y mostrar por que el formato viene asi desde la base de datos (SQL):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo he hecho antes mostrándolo dentro de grillas pero nunca hacerlo como punteo o listado, lo que siempre hago es recibir el Datatable desde la base de datos y luego pasarlo a una lista la cual es recibida como data en el JS y luego mostrada en la grilla por ejemplo pero nunca lo he hecho como un punteo o mostrándola como

Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida

**El lenguaje usado es C# con framework .net y JS junto a JQUERY**

Otra herramienta que utilizo es KENDO UI pero no conosco un input que sea parecido a una lista punteada para llenarlo desde el backend.

Muchas Gracias!!!

Comment: Fácil, creas una lista no ordenada `<ul>`, haces un ciclo para mostrar los datos `<li>Información de cada resultado</li>` y terminas cerrando la lista `</ul>`.

Comment: claro tienes razón no se me había ocurrido intentarlo con un <ul></ul> lo intentare gracias!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Puedes recorrer tu array de datos con un `forEach` y acceder a la etiqueta `ul` para insertar cada uno de los datos.

Ejemplo:

```js
var list = [
  'Eum perferendis aliquam id.',
  'Voluptatum recusandae eligendi eius rerum ut nemo error.',
  'Dolores ex nobis vel ipsa deleniti nulla doloribus.',
];
var listView = document.querySelector('#list');

list.forEach((item) => {
  listView.innerHTML += `<li>${item}</li>`;
});
```

```html
<ul id="list"></ul>
```

Puedes ver mas acerca de como usar una lista en `HTML` [aqui](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_lists.asp)

Comment: Muchas Gracias Chicos esto mismo estaba buscando ahí me funciono Perfectamente!!!!.